# Cordova is not listed after updated Xcode and IOS

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I have updated my operating system to Mac OS X El Capitan and I updated my Xcode to 7.3.Now I can not build my Ionic project and getting the the Codova is not listed in my cli..

I used the following comment

```
ionic info
```

And the output:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: Not installed
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:  
Ionic Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.11
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: 1.8.5 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175
```

I tried to install the Cordova but i does not help still getting the same.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: what happens when you try to install cordova again? post error messages if you get any

Comment: @jcesarmobile i resolved the issue by restared the system

Comment: good to know, restars are lifesavers